# PHP, Regular expression to extract string to float number

Tags: php, regex

I have a string = '0.25MM X 1219MM X COIL'.
Also sometimes those string is = '0.25MM X 1219MM'

I try With regular expression :

```
 preg_match_all('!\d+!', trim($modelCoil['size']), $matches);
 VarDumper::dump($matches);
```

I get :

```
[
   0 => [
      0 => '0'
      1 => '25'
      2 => '1219'
   ]
]
```

The result that expected :

```
[
    0 => '0.25.00'
    1 => '1219.00'
]
```

Please advise.

Comment: `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is just searching for `\d+`. You are wanting to include decimal points (`.`) in your results.

You might want to try searching for `\d[\d\.]*` or similar to include the dot.